# Can I create a semaphore with locked transactions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a service that requires maintaining a pool of external resources. Therefore I have a table to track the pool. Each row can be used by one user once. My thought was that I can start a transaction, use a lock, try to update row, and see if it errors from having a lock. However it seems my attempt during a lock just makes MySQL wait for the lock to end before making the update happen.

```sql
# process 1
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM pool WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE pool SET claimed=1 WHERE id=1;
# (run process 2 below before this commits)
COMMIT;

# process 2
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM pool WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE;
# this hangs until above commit
UPDATE pool SET claimed=1 WHERE id=1;
COMMIT;
```

I know I can lower the lock timeout but that would possibly impact other queries negatively. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm going for via MySQL?

I should note that in reality I will be doing a `SELECT` on the table for things where `claimed=0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`. If the update throws an exception I plan to do another `SELECT` to find another row, while the successful path would `DELETE` the row. Doing the example with `id=1` is for simplicity in testing :)

Comment: Have you tried removing `FOR UPDATE` and checked?

Comment: That would mean nothing is locked so nothing would ever throw an exception. In the meantime I am just checking if the row updated. If it didn't update, I know it was claimed and go try to find another item from pool.

Comment: MySQL-8.0 / MariaDB-10.6 have `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` to prevent hanging because the actual pool item doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A -- If the task takes only a few seconds,

```
    START TRANSACTION;
    do all the task (possibly including FOR UPDATE)
    COMMIT;
```

Plan B -- If the task takes longer than a few seconds.  (Note:  The `UPDATEs` can probably be done with a single statement, hence no need for a transaction.)

```
    (with autocommit=ON)
    UPDATE ... to grab an item and announce who has the item
    do the task
    UPDATE ... to release the item
```

Plan C -- Read about `GET_LOCK()` and `RELEASE_LOCK()`.  Note that there is a timeout on the GET.

`lock_wait_timeout` (which applies to Plan A) defaults to 50 seconds.  But I think you should not have transactions that last anywhere near that long.  Hence, Plan B.

Yes, Plan A might include

```
SELECT .. WHERE claimed=0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1  FOR UPDATE;
```

But notice the `FOR UPDATE`.  And there should be no case for failure.  You have limited the choices to `claimed=0`.  Caution:  if this is a huge table, the random selection will take time.